# Hide entire <tr> if child's child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey

I have a table like this

```js
$('td:contains("label label-primary")').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-primary">
          HIDE
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-danger">
          SHOW
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I just want to be able to hide the table rows in which the `span` deep inside the tr has a specific class. In this case, `label label-primary`.

However, this does not seem to work. It hides nothing.

I am using this on tampermonkey to edit a webpage whose code I do not have edition access.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains()` selects all elements that contain the specified text. You want to use `find()` (https://api.jquery.com/find/) or `:has()` https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/ to select based on a selector. You also have to write ".label.label-primary" to indicate they are classes.

`$('td:has(.label.label-primary)').parent().hide();
OR
$('td').find('.label.label-primary').parent().hide();`

Comment: Thank you. I am very noob at all this and you just made my day. I forgot about the class nomenclature. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span').hasClass('label label-primary').parents('tr:first').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector to check element contains at least one element that matches the specified selector. Or use [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method to filter out elements.

```js
$('td:has(".label.label-primary")').parent().hide();

// or
$('tr:has("td .label.label-primary")').hide();

// or using has method
$('tr').has("td .label.label-primary").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
          <span class="label label-primary">
                          ble>          HIDE
                                </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
          <span class="label label-danger">
                                    SHOW
                                </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  $(".table td").filter(function() {
     return $('span', this).hasClass('label.label-primary');
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a one liner solution, hope it helps:

```js
$("tr > td > a").find("span[class*='label label-primary']").closest("tr").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-primary">
                                    HIDE
                                </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-danger">
                                    SHOW
                                </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you this jquery script?

```
$('td').find(".label.label-primary").closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: `$('td .label.label-primary').closest('tr').hide();` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('span[class="label label-primary"]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-primary">
          HIDE
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="pums" rel="tooltip">
        <span class="label label-danger">
          SHOW
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Just loop through all the `tr` & then find `span` with specific class.

Hope this will help you.